# Regular expression not working in names_pattern in pivot_longer in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, tidyr, stringr

I struggle with regular expressions. I am trying to pivot a table from a census of the number of people of each sex in each area. This is the format of the column names...

```
"Females:\r\nAged 4 years and under [note 12]"
"Females: Aged 5 to 9 years [note 12]" ... 
"Males: Aged 65 to 69 years [note 12]" ... 
"Males: Aged 90 years and over [note 12]"
```

... and so forth.
The original data frame looks like

| Area | Females: Aged 4 years and under [note 12] | Females: Aged 5 to 9 years [note 12] | ... etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| england | 45 | 56 | ... |
| wales | 24 | 56 | ... |

(numbers made up). This is my current code/attempt:

```
sex_age_areapiv <- pivot_longer(sex_age_area, 
             cols = 4:41,
             names_to = c("sex", "age_range"),
             names_sep = "Aged",
            # names_pattern = "(.*): Aged (.*)", #option 1??
            # names_pattern = "((Fe)|(M)ale): Aged (.*)", #option 2??
             values_to = "count")
```

Using the pivot vignette I tried option 1 but no separation of names happened. After reading a bit more on regular expressions, Option 2 had the same result.

I currently have names_sep = "Aged" and then tidy up the values by using str_remove or str_replace but would like to learn how to do it within pivot_longer. Ideally, I would like to end up with three columns: "sex", "age_range" and "count" where the values for each is taken from this section of the string/column name:

**"sex"** s: Aged **"age_range"** years [note 12]"

| sex | age_range | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Female | 4 | 6 |
| Female | 5 to 9 | 8 |
| Male | 10 to 9 | 10 |
| Male | 90 | 11 |

I have a feeling is the under 4s and over 90s causing the problem :(

Comment: I do not understand. Could you please clarify and provide how the first dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c('sex', 'age_range'), 
               names_pattern =  "(?s)(\\w+):.*Aged ?(\\d+.*) years")
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id sex     age_range value
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 Females 4             6
2     1 Females 5 to 9        8
3     1 Males   65 to 69     10
4     1 Males   90           11
```

---

data_used:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1, `Females:\n\rAged 4 years and under [note 12]` = 6, 
    `Females: Aged 5 to 9 years [note 12]` = 8, `Males: Aged 65 to 69 years [note 12]` = 10, 
    `Males: Aged 90 years and over [note 12]` = 11), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @onyambu - could you please explain how you got to the regular expression solution? Thanks!

Comment: @bioscianalyst the issue is the presence of `\n` and the ICU engine that stringR uses, `.` metacharacter does not match `\n` thus we need to invoke `(?s)` whch ensures that the string is read in as a single string making `.` to mach `\n`. Note that base R uses PCRE and not ICU hence in base R `.` does match `\n`. Check here for the quick flag options `https://www.codeguage.com/courses/regexp/flags`